# GNUplot Multiplot - changing background color of a few plots

Tags: gnuplot

I have a multiplot of 3*3 = 9 plots on 1 page of GNUPlot output. How can I change the background color of just 2 of these plots? - So, out of the 9 plots, 7 plots should have white background and 2 can have yellow for example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You may specify the background color of individual sub-plots with :

```
set object 1 rectangle from graph 0,0 to graph 1,1 behind fillcolor rgb 'yellow' fillstyle solid noborder
```

with 'yellow' or 'white' depending on the desired background color. 
This has to be inserted before each `plot` command. 
If you simply want to return to the default background color (instead of 'white') then you may use `unset object 1`.